# Function.prototype.apply doesn't work on Function.prototype.call in Chrome

Tags: javascript

The title should be self explanatory, and I wonder if there is a workaround for this.

```
Window.call.apply;
>> function apply()

Window.call.apply();

>> Uncaught TypeError: Window.call.apply is not a function
    at <anonymous>:2:13
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateOn (<anonymous>:895:140)
    at Object.InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap (<anonymous>:828:34)
    at Object.InjectedScript.evaluate (<anonymous>:694:21)
```

Basically, I am surprised that `apply` works on every function except one.

I am writing some higher level VM that needs to call native javascript functions (sadly, `Function.prototype.call` is one of them), so I need the function `apply` to be able to pass my this context and array of arguments.

**Updated:**
It seems that this is just some weird error message.
I found this when I wanted to be able to call a constructor with variable number of arguments and passing `this` explicitly, which is an object instead of the expected function.

Perhaps below is a more realistic example:

```
function Fruit(name) {
  this.name = name;
}
var x = {};
Fruit.call(x, "Apple");
// I thought this would also work, but it throws above error message
(Fruit.call).apply(x, ["Apple"]);
// Should instead use the constructor directly
Fruit.apply(x, ["Apple"]);
// or
(Fruit.call).apply(someFunction, [x, "Apple"]);
```

Comment: In Firefox I get `TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined`, which makes sense.

Comment: Huh, I guess only Chrome has this issue then.

Comment: Nah, the error message is just different and confusing. `Window.call.apply(function foo() { console.log('foo'); });` works perfectly fine.

Comment: Apply call on Window and it'll work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the error because you are not passing an argument to `.apply`. Firefox throws a more reasonable error:

> TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined

It works fine in both browsers if you actually pass a function that should be called:

```js
Window.call.apply(function foo() { console.log('foo'); });
```

---

Note: If you actually want to apply the `Window` function to an arbitrary object, this probably won't work. Host objects/functions are often more restrictive, especially when it involves the DOM.